# Cakephp find 10 most view products

Tags: cakephp

I want to write a cake php query , in which i want to find out 10(limit) most viewed products.  In my products table i created a field as 'views', it increase by 1 on every view. Now i want the list of 10 most view products in my admin panel.  Using $topViewed =
`$this->Product->find('all',array(
           'limit'=>10,
            'conditions'=>array('Product.status'=>1),
           'fields'=>array('id','title','view_count'),
           'recursive' => -1,
            ));`  .

above query shows me result but not as per most viewed product. I want 10 most viewed products arrange higher to lower. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the "order" parameter:

```
$this->Product->find('all',array(
    'limit'=>10,
    'conditions'=>array('Product.status'=>1),
    'fields'=>array('id','title','view_count'),
    'order' => 'Product.view DESC', // <-- THIS
    'recursive' => -1,
));
```

Side note: Ideally, you'd be setting recursive to -1 in your AppModel, so you wouldn't have to set it for every query.

Comment: hi dave, thanks .. I am just missing the point. thanks it worked.